# Changing style works only partially: text color changes, background doesn't

Tags: java, android, styles, android-styles

I'm trying to change the style of a Button when someone clicks on it. I want to change both the background as the text colour. However, only the text color is changed. From that I conclude that the style *is* changed, but for some reason the background can't be overwritten.

I'm using this code in the onClick handler:

```java
Button send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
send_button.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.activeButtonTheme);
```

The relevant styles in my styles.xml are:

```xml
<style name="buttonTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
</style>

<style name="activeButtonTheme" parent="@style/buttonTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

What's the problem here?

I do not want to set the background color from Java, I only want to change the style in Java.

Comment: Ensure that no call to `setBackground` is present in your java code.

Comment: @AdamArold there is nothing except this and an alertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selector` for that purpose. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) for details(**Custom background** section) Regarding to your code, define appropriate *selector.xml* file in your resources directory, something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_dissabled_button" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_pressed_button" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_enabled_button" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_for_enabled_button" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

Assign just created selector to the button in the layout file:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/your_button_id"
    android:background="@drawable/selector" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Could you also say why what I tried doesn't work? Is there something special about the `background` property?

Comment: As I know changing the style after creating the view is not supported.

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the text color is changed; that's the weird thing about all this.